# Multiple JSON Encode By AJAX Call

Tags: php, json, ajax

I want to get server response from PHP script called by AJAX using these code:

**index.php:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: "insert.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $("form").serializeArray(),
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.loader').show();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $txt = 'Min: ' + data.num1 + ' | Max: ' + data.num2 + ' | Numeration: ' + data.id;
        $('p').prepend($txt);
        $('.loader').hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**insert.php**

```js
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];

$post_data = $_POST;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  $id['id'] = $i;
  $data = array_merge($id, $post_data);
  sleep(1);
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

How to possibly send multiple json_encode by AJAX call?

Comment: Make an array, append to it in the loop, encode the entire array after the loop…

Comment: Yes indeed, but I want a delay between the loop while send the result to the page.

Comment: There's no good way to do that if you're not using web sockets.

Comment: I've seen few native web installer can do this w/o using web socket, i.e. showing installation progress message on page.